# 500 (Internal Server Error) get images

Tags: jquery

have problem with get images satellite from sat24 , and they update him site .

link images : http://en.sat24.com/image/lightning?type=visual&region=sa&timestamp= timeupdate , he have to be 201508241430

http://en.sat24.com/image/lightning?type=visual&region=sa&timestamp=201508241430.

jquery

```
var arrayImageTimes = [];arrayImageTimes.push('201508241245');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241300');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241315');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241330');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241345');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241400');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241415');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241430');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241445');arrayImageTimes.push('201508241500');
```

Comment: That is a huge amount of code and almost no problem description given. Remove all irrelevant code and provide a proper description of what is going wrong

Comment: i just want get update time http://en.sat24.com/image/lightning?type=visual&region=sa&timestamp=  timeupdate

Comment: Please be more specific and keep in mind we don't know that api

Comment: i update the Questions , if you don't the answer please keep away

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, nobody else is trying to help you. It is up to you to make the problem understandable if you want solutions for it. Right now it is not clear whatsoever what the problem is other than you have a 500 error. Also there is zero troubleshooting information given as to what you have done to try to isolate the root of the error. Telling someone to keep away is not being respectful to those that try to help on their own time

Comment: just the time , anyway thanks

Comment: `just the time` from what? I recognize English may not be your first language but you will need to try to give more defintiive explanations

Comment: i want code update the time auto , look on the Question in ulr